# Jacobson radical of a finite commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring, and let $J$ be the Jacobson radical of R (the intersection of all the maximal ideals of R).

> (1) Prove that $J^n=0$ for some $n$.
>
> (2) Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to show that $R/J\cong F_1\times ...\times F_m$
> for some $m$, where every $F_i$ is a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1)$ There are a lot of proofs of this fact. Some of this:

- $R$ is finite and then Artinian. In an artinian ring the Jacobson radical is equal to the Nilradical an so nilpotent.
- $J$ is finitely generated as $R$-module and by Nakayama's lemma $J^2\neq J$ or $J=0$. The chain of powers of $J$ must stabilize by the finiteness of $R$ and then must exist $n$ such that $J^n=J^{n+1}$ and by Nakayama $J^n=0$

$2)$ If $R$ is finite then it has a finite number of maximal ideals $M_1, \dots, M_n$. Then $J=M_1 \cdots M_n$ and then

$$R/J \simeq R/M_1 \cdots M_n \simeq R/M_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus R/M_n $$

Comment: Excellent Joseph